# NSCalendar showing as military time but location is using 12-hour time (Swift/iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, date, time, uidatepicker

I have the simulator's location in the US and the calendar type as Gregorian. The UIDatePicker shows the time in 12-hour format; however when I update the timeLabel I'm seeing that the time is in military time. I was wondering why is this so? I could quickly fix this by creating a function to convert from military to 12-hour time but I do not want to meddle with that in case a user does want military time.

```
@IBAction func timePicked(sender: UIDatePicker)
    {
        let date = sender.date
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: date)
        day.hours = components.hour
        day.minutes = components.minute
        updateTimeLabel()
    }
```

Edit:

```
func updateTimeLabel()
    {
        self.timeLabel?.text = "Notify me at: " + day.description
    }
```

With `day` being an object that displays its hour and minutes in the form hour:minute

Comment: Can you show the code for `updateTimeLabel`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you say they may want either 24h or 12h, give them the choice.

That way you can have the code that displays in 24h or 12h.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var twentyFourHours: UISwitch!

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    @IBOutlet weak var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timeMode(twentyFourHours)


    }

    @IBAction func datePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {

       let stringDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myDatePicker.date)
        self.timeLabel.text = stringDate


    }

    @IBAction func timeMode(sender: UISwitch) {

    if twentyFourHours.on {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    } else {

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"


        }

     datePicker(myDatePicker)

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

The above works in my quick test and is only an example. Notice I am using a formatter to do the format for the label and a UISwtch for the user to choose 24h or 12h.

The format for 12 is  `"hh:mm a"`  the a on the end is if to display the AM/PM

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer! in your example the datepicker remains 12-hour time for both because it detects the area with the corresponding time format. i was wondering if there was a way to access the data that tells whether it is 12/24 hours? or if the datepicker could be changed to 24 hour format?

Comment: Good choice of time